# How to initiate python logging instance once

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I have a python 3 project with several scripts `.py`.

`main.py`, `script1.py`, `script2.py`, `script3.py`, `logger.py`.  `main.py` includes the 3 script/modules.

I created a logger class inherited from logging module. Currently, in each of the `.py` module I have to instantiate the logger class and set loglevel/loggername/log path individually.

Is there a way to set the logging level / loggername (or no need) / log path in main.py so that the same level can be passed within this project without setup them individually in each script?

Comment: Maybe show your logger class, surely you could set the logging level, name and path in the logger class __init__ such that any of your other scripts calling to it will be getting the same settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way. More than this, it is the **best practice way**.

The python logging is hierarchical by the logger name, so log that called "abc.def" is treated as the child of logger named "abc". All loggers have an ancestor named "root" logger.

So, if you want (and usually you want) a centralized log configuration you should configure the root logger `logging.getLogger()`.

If you like, you can do it easily with `logging.basicConfig` helper function.

Then all your other loggers will go by this configuration.

If you want a specific configuration to some logs, you can configure them selectively or by "families root" using the names hierarchy.

Edit: for multiple logs configuration you can also have a centralized `logging.conf` file like explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging).

Comment: thanks Lior, " If you want a specific configuration to some logs, you can configure them selectively or by "families root" using the names hierarchy." How do I specify the logLevel/logpath etc in the main.py for other scripts???

Comment: No path. names. log1 = logging.getLogger('log_name'). log1.set....

Comment: also logging.conf file. see Edit in my answer.